# Why is cross_val_score substantially lower than .score or roc_auc_score?

Tags: python, cross-validation, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I have a trained model, a GradientBoostingClassifier. My dataset is 60 thousand something rows of data that I've split into 66/33 train/test sets. Scoring the model via the `.score()` method or via `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score()` returns quite reasonable scores:

```
In: gbc.score(x_test, y_test)
Out: 0.8958226221079691
In: roc_auc_score(y_test, gbc.predict(x_test))
Out: 0.8899345768861056
```

That 'aint so bad. However when I use `cross_val_score` I'm getting a substantially lower value:

```
In: scores = cross_val_score(gbc, df, target, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc')
In: scores.mean()
Out: 0.5646406271571536
```

The documentation for cross_val_score says by default it uses the default .score method of the model you're using, but that passing a value to the "scoring" parameter can alter that. I've tried both but am somehow getting results that are quite wildly different from both the default `.score` method and from the `roc_auc_score` method that I assume `cross_val_score` uses when I pass `scoring='roc_auc'`.

I could understand why this might be the case if I had used GridSearchCV to tune the hyper parameters of the model; in that case I would assume that I've overfit it to the testing set of data. However:

1) I haven't done any tuning at all, it's literally using default parameters
2) I tried to test this by running the following:

```
val_scores = []
test_scores = []

for x in range(10):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        df,
        target,
        test_size=0.33
    )

    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.5)

    gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier()
    gbc.fit(x_train, y_train)
    test_scores.append(gbc.score(x_test, y_test))
    val_scores.append(gbc.score(x_val, y_val))

test_scores.mean()
val_scores.mean()
```

And the scores on both the test and val slices are north of 0.89. There's no random_state in play here so I would expect train_test_split to be slicing randomly enough that any accidental overfitting based on the default parameters of the model really ought to be negated.

So; why might cross_val_score be reporting scores significantly lower than either .score or roc_auc_score?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I eventually found the answer, in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688058/sklearn-cross-val-score-gives-lower-accuracy-than-manual-cross-validation

which is that by default the means through which cross_val_score slices the folds in my case, StratifiedKFold, doesn't select a random subset of the data but rather just the "top n rows" or something similar. As my data is sorted by date and then by a particular feature this means it has to predict the DV later when it's not necessarily seen some of the values in those 2 features. The answer is to explicitly pass a StratifiedKFold with the `shuffle` parameter set to True:

```
 s = cross_val_score(
    df,
    target,
    cv=StratifiedKFold(shuffle=True),
    scoring='roc_auc'
)
s.mean()
0.9595958053830161
```

Note that the score is higher because I think it's using predict_proba(), which makes sense.